# How to spin an image and stop it spinning at a random angle?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to spin an image and after 3 seconds it must stop at a random angle (from `360` to `10800` degrees). It should start to spin from the last position when it is clicked.

When the image stops spinning, a random citation should appear in a nearby area. I am trying to achieve an effect like "spin the bottle"

I want to use CSS or JavaScript. Here is my code so far:

```css
.wheel {
  animation: wheel 3s .5s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes wheel {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(10800deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bottle.css">
  <script src="bottle.js"></script>
</head>
<img id="wheel" class="wheel" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/grinning-face-smile-emoji-happy-37705.png">
```

Comment: Take a look at the random (sass) function, explained here: https://codepen.io/dan10gc/post/use-the-random-sass-function-to-create-unique-animations

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with css custom properties. The first thing to do is create a property for your transform:

```
:root{
  --rot: rotate(108000deg);
}
```

And then use that in place of your hard-coded value

```
@keyframes wheel {
  from { transform: rotate(0);}             
  to { transform: var(--rot); }
}
```

At this stage everything should carry on working as before.

Now you can manipulate that property with javascipt:

```js
var min = 360;
var max = 108000;
var rnd = Math.random()* (max - min) + min;
console.log(rnd);

var wheel = document.querySelector(".wheel");
wheel.style.setProperty("--rot","rotate(" + rnd + "deg)");
```

```css
:root{
  --rot: rotate(108000deg);
}

.wheel {    
  animation: wheel 3s .5s; 
  animation-fill-mode: both; 
}

@keyframes wheel {
  from { transform: rotate(0);}    
  to { transform: var(--rot); }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bottle.css">
<script src="bottle.js"></script>
</head>
<img id="wheel" class="wheel" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/grinning-face-smile-emoji-happy-37705.png">
```

If you want to repeat the animation on something like a click you need to doa bit of a workaround

```js
var min = 360;
var max = 108000;

var wheel = document.querySelector("#wheel");
wheel.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  
  // -> removing the class
  wheel.classList.remove("wheel");
  
  // -> triggering reflow /* The actual magic */
  // without this it wouldn't work. Try uncommenting the line and the transition won't be retriggered.
  // Oops! This won't work in strict mode. Thanks Felis Phasma!
  // element.offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;
  // Do this instead:
  void wheel.offsetWidth;
  
  var rnd = Math.random()* (max - min) + min;
  console.log(rnd);
  wheel.style.setProperty("--rot","rotate(" + rnd + "deg)");
  // -> and re-adding the class
  wheel.classList.add("wheel");
}, false);
```

```css
:root{
  --rot: rotate(108000deg);
}

.wheel {    
  animation: wheel 3s .5s; 
  animation-fill-mode: both; 
}

@keyframes wheel {   
  to { transform: var(--rot); }
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bottle.css">
<script src="bottle.js"></script>
</head>
<img id="wheel" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/grinning-face-smile-emoji-happy-37705.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner approach to spin the element with random degree;

```js
let rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (10800 - 360 + 1)) + 360;
document.querySelector(".wheel").style = `transform:rotate(${rnd}deg)`;
```

```css
.wheel {    
  animation: wheel 3s .5s; 
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes wheel {
  to { transform: rotate(0deg);}    
}
```

```html
<img class="wheel" src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/grinning-face-smile-emoji-happy-37705.png">
```